# Preferred method for setting a row as a header after transposing a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, header

**What's the best practice for such a simple task?**

Is there any way to speed up the messy lines of code with a simple method?

Let's say we have the following raw data:

```
#Example Data
df = pd.read_csv('example.csv', header = None, sep=';')
display(df)
```

[image]

To manipulate the data appropriately we transpose and edit:

```
#Transpose the Dataframe
df = df.transpose()
display(df)

#Set the first row as a header
header_row = 0 #<-- Input, should be mandatory? could it be default?

#Set the column names to the first row values
df.columns = df.iloc[header_row]

#Get rid of the unnecessary row
df = df.drop(header_row).reset_index(drop=True)

#Display final result
display(df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply do that by

```
df.set_index(0,inplace=True)
df.T
```

an example of same kind is given below

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({"Col":[9,8,0],"Row":[6,4,22],"id":[26,55,27]})
df2

    Col     Row     id
0   9   6   26
1   8   4   55
2   0   22  27

df2.set_index("id",inplace=True)
df2.T

id  26  55  27
Col     9   8   0
Row     6   4   22
```

Comment: That's even shorter, I like it :)